# Why is jqplot behaving this way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, jqplot

I have a chart that consists of 4 series. Three of the four are stacked bar charts and the forth is a line. Why is the graph acting this way? I assumed that it didn't matter in what order I passed in the series to the `$.jqPlot` function. I thought you would be able to adjust your series by using the `series` property and just giving an empty object for ones you didn't want to adjust.

scoreArray is the series I want to be a line chart that I want overlayed over the bars. My first attempt was with this code:

```
$.jqplot("HistoryChart",
    [scoreArray, AvailableArray, UnavailableArray, UnknownArray], {
        stackSeries: true,
        seriesDefaults : {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions : {
                barWidth: 40
            }
        },
        series : [{
            disableStack : true,
            renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer
        }, {}, {}, {}],
        axesDefaults : {
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                angle: -45
            }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis : {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: dateArray
            }
        }
    }
);
```

This is the generated graph:

[image]

Now if I made scoreArray the last series and adjusted the series property accordingly, it looks correct. Here is the code and graph:

```
$.jqplot("HistoryChart",
    [AvailableArray, UnavailableArray, UnknownArray, scoreArray], {
        stackSeries: true,
        seriesDefaults : {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions : {
                barWidth: 40
            }
        },
        series : [{}, {}, {}, {
            disableStack : true,
            renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer
        }],
        axesDefaults : {
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                angle: -45
            }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis : {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: dateArray
            }
        }
    }
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like a bug to me. 
You have not set y axis min-max, which is skewing the initial setup of the axis.
Try setting the min. It may work

Answer (score 0):

The option `disableStack: true` should start a new stacked plot from that series. When you would have put it on the first bar plot on the first example you would get the same graph. See the modified code:

```
.jqplot("HistoryChart",
[scoreArray, AvailableArray, UnavailableArray, UnknownArray], {
    stackSeries: true,
    seriesDefaults : {
        renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
        rendererOptions : {
            barWidth: 40
        }
    },
    series : [{
        renderer: $.jqplot.LineRenderer
    }, 
    {
        disableStack : true
    }, {}, {}],
    axesDefaults : {
        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
        tickOptions: {
            angle: -45
        }
    },
    axes: {
        xaxis : {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
            ticks: dateArray
        }
    }
}
);
```

But that doesn't seem to work:
[image: Messed up graph]

It appears not to be supported to call it on a bar chart. =

So the only way to make it work is add the line series as last series and add the `disableStack : true` on these line series.

Comment: your series array looks like it sets disableStack on AvailableArray array. Is that what you wanted? I thought it would be on the first array index.

Comment: According to the examples I had seen I thought it would work this way, on the first bar plot, but I get some pretty interesting results using this code: http://i.imgur.com/dV3IrtH.png